# Adding an AD Group to a large Public drive via Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting, windows-server-2016, ntfs

We have a large file share that houses about 1tb of data.
The following location has about 600 folders beneath it.
F:\Data
The task is to assign a specific AD group read permissions to every folder inside of the data folder, the subfolders do not matter.

I am trying to see if the script below would be the best approach?
my concern is this is a file server and I don't want to break anything
or mess up any rights, also not to sure if while the script is running and their
is a file open would it cause am error.

I have tried running this script in a test environment and it worked great , but there is no error log where even if it stopped somewhere i would be able to check.

I could be overthinking it, but just wanted to see if anyone has experienced anything like this?

```
$StartingPath = "PATH"
$Right = "Read"
$Principal = "Domain\ADGroup"

$Rule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Principal,$Right,"Allow")

foreach ($Folder in $(Get-ChildItem -Directory $StartingPath -Recurse)) {
$Acl=Get-Acl $Folder.FullName
$Acl.SetAccessRule($Rule)
Set-Acl $folder.Fullname $Acl
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to experiment with Inheritance and Propagation (use your test environment for that) and use the overloaded method with 5 parameters to create your new accessrule for that.

That way, you only add the new rule to the main data share folder and do not have to iterate all subfolders.

```
# FileSystemRights:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights
# Inheritance flags: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.inheritanceflags
# Propagation flags: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.propagationflags

$Principal  = "TheADGroupWithReadPermissions"
$accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Principal, "Read", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow")
$acl = Get-Acl "F:\Data"
$acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
Set-Acl -Path "F:\Data" -ACLObject $acl
```

Difference between `AddAccessRule()` and `SetAccessRule()`:

| AddAccessRule | SetAccessRule |
| --- | --- |
| This method will add this access rule to the ACL. If a user or group has Modify permission and we use AddAccessRule() to create a new rule with Read permission the user or group will *still also have* Modify permissions. | This method removes any existing access and *replaces that access* with the specified rule. If a user or group has Modify permission and a new rule is created using SetAccessRule() specifying Read permission, that user or group will now only have Read permission. |

Comment: That worked perfectly what i ended up doing was setting it to AddAccessRule and Inheritance and propagation i set them both to none. I tested in a few different scenarios and the permissions did not propagate down to the sub folders.   Is there an easy way to create a success or fail , this way when i run it and it happens to freeze or end i can know where it left off?

Comment: @DLINK Glad to have helped. BTW You may not know this, but it's customary to mark the question 'done' by accepting the answer. To do that you click the large checkmark icon to the left. This will help others with a similar question finding it more easily.

Comment: @DLINK If you sett inheritance to all 'none' , the ace is.. well, not inherited by child folders or leaf objects.  That's why I think you need `"ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit"` or at least `"ContainerInherit,None"` to have subfolders inherit the main folder's ace. If the main folder has many items, then yes, it will take its time..

Comment: I have added the checkmark my apologies , your info was very helpful, i ended up running it with None and you mentioned and it worked great.